# Why does my redis keep shutting my site down

Tags: craft3, error

I uploaded a new site (migrated) to a new server. 3 times now I've had my redis maxout memory.  This causes my site to show an error 500.  When I flush the redris the site goes back up immediately.  I can't seem to find what is the issue though.  Where would I start looking to address it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check your Redis server's eviction policy, which describes what Redis should do when it runs out of memory: https://docs.redis.com/latest/rs/databases/memory-performance/eviction-policy/

Most Redis servers use `allkeys-lru` by default, which means it will removes the least recently used (oldest) keys to free up memory for new ones.

Comment: Thanks Brad, it was on volatile-lru.  I'll see if this fixes it!